# How to go back multiple Pages?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, uwp

In my Universal app, I want to use a `Frame` to navigate through my app. I also have a breadcrumb, as per the designs. Now I don't really know how to handle things when the user wants to go back multiple pages.

My breadcrumb items are simple strings that I display using a `XAML` `ListView`. I find the index of the breadcrumb the user clicked on and I try to go back so many times.

I tried using a for loop:

```
private void Breadcrumb_Item_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var breadcrumb = ((sender as Grid).DataContext as string);

    for(int i = 1; i < Breadcrumbs.Count - Breadcrumbs.indexOf(breadcrumb); i++)
    {
        frame.GoBack();
    }
}
```

But the `frame.GoBack()` doesn't always work, I'm guessing because it is going too fast after the `GoBack()` call before. I don't want to use a sleep method, because it should be instant.

What can I do to go back multiple pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using `frame.BackStack.RemoveAt(frame.BackStackDepth-1)`

This way you will remove the entries from the stack without actually navigating.
Use a loop to decide  when you should stop removing and then execute a final `frame.GoBack()`

Comment: So I remove until the last one on the backstack is one ahead of where I want to be and then I do a `frame.GoBack()` to pop the last one?

Comment: @vrwim Did it work? If not maybe we can see what went wrong and find another solution.

Comment: Yep it worked, I just had to manually remove items from my breadcrumb, as I only had that code in the `frame.Navigating` event and removing items from the `BackStack` doesn't do that.